# How can I play audio files in ElectronJS

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron

I have tried every single method on every post here and on github.
I tried using an HTML audio tag, creating a new window that plays the audio using the ipcRenderer/ipcMain API, and trying every single library to play sounds and still nothing. Does anyone have an idea on how to play audio files in it?

Comment: Share your code and the errors you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few days of thorough testing and trying, I found out the way to play audio files using the Protocol API in ElectronJS:

In the main process:

```
import { protocol } from "electron"

// ... some other code here
const registerAssetProtocol = async (): Promise<void> => {
      return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
        protocol.registerFileProtocol('asset', (request, callback) => {
          const assetName = request.url.substr(8); // Remove 'asset://'
          const assetPath = path.normalize(
            path.join(__dirname, '../assets/', assetName)
          );
          console.log('Asset Path:', assetPath);

          callback({
            path: assetPath,
            headers: {
              'content-type': 'audio/mpeg',
            },
          });
        });

        // Due to the way registerFileProtocol works, it doesn't provide a direct error callback.
        // If there's an error, you would have to handle it inside the callback itself.
        // Here, we're simply resolving after the registration attempt.
        resolve();
      });
    };
```

And then in the component where you would like to play the audio file, in my case a react component and the audio file triggers on the click of an element:

```
// This is the function that triggers the audio play
// ... some other code here
  function toggleCompletionState() {
    if (!isComplete) {
      // Assuming you want to play the audio when task is completed
      const todoCompletionChime = new Audio(
        'asset://audio/chimes/todoCompletionChime.mp3'
      );
      todoCompletionChime.play();
    }

    setIsComplete(!isComplete);
  }
//... other code here
   <button
          type="button"
          className={`rounded-full h-7 w-7 flex flex-row items-center justify-center ${
            isComplete ? 'bg-success' : 'bg-white'
          }`}
          onClick={toggleCompletionState}
        >
```

And this is the button that plays the audio file, and make sure you set the path of the protocol the same in both the main process and the renderer (in my case "asset"
If anyone has any better approach or a better way to do it, please answer so in the comments.